# Source for prohibition of standing outside the shul during amida

Tags: halacha, synagogue, tefillah-betzibbur

I've heard Rabbi Shay Tahan saying that a person doing amida outside the shul, the rabbis say that he like worshipping another god.

What's the source for this?

Comment: Here's the discussion: https://www.betmidrash.org.il/index.php/%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Shulchan Aruch OC 90:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.90.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). The issue is to avoid giving the impression one prays with his back to the synagogue and treats it and the congregation with contempt but see the details below

> **Neither should one pray behind a synagogue, if one does not face the
> synagogue**. Behind a synagogue means the side of the opening, which is
> opposite the side that the community faces in prayer. There are,
> however, those who understand [the term 'behind'] differently, and it
> is fitting to heed to both opinions, and even when praying on other
> sides on the outside of the synagogue one should take care to face the
> synagogue itself.
>
> All of this applies when it seems obvious that one
> is turning their back to the synagogue, but if one prays in a house
> attached to a synagogue and turns one's face toward the Land of
> Israel, as is proper, and one's back faces the wall of the house which
> is also the synagogue - this is permitted, because it doesn't appear
> as if one's face is turned away from the synagogue.

The source for this is in [Brachot 6b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.6b.18?lang=bi) (translation R Steinsaltz)

> Back to the topic of deference for a synagogue, the Gemara records
> that Rav Huna said: One who prays behind the synagogue is called
> wicked, as while the entire congregation is facing one direction to
> pray, he faces the opposite direction creating the impression that he
> is treating the synagogue and its congregation with contempt. As it is
> stated: “The wicked walk round about, when vileness is exalted among
> the sons of men” (Psalms 12:9). In other words, only the wicked walk
> round about the synagogue in order to pray.